# Docker Service Cannot Identify the Mounted Azure File Share in Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-server-2016, file-storage, azure-files

I tried bind mounting a "Azure-Files" file share for docker swarm service in Windows server 2016.

First I mounted the file-share to H:\ driver and mounting was successful.
I could created files and folders in H:\ driver via file explorer.

Created following directory tree.
H:\windows\ema-home

Then I bind mount this directory to the container's c:\enactor\app\home location.

Service deployment fails with following error.
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: H:\windows\ema-home"

I've tried same in Ubuntu-Server-18.04 and docker swarm service worked fine.

```
---
version: '3.3'

services:
  em-application:
    image: enactordev-on.azurecr.io/enactorstandard/win/ema:2.4.175.125
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    ports:
      - target: 39830
        published: 39830
        mode: host                 
    volumes:
      - H:\windows\ema-home:c:\enactor\app\home  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After some in-depth researching figured out the this is a limitation in windows-containers. For further information please refer to the following discussions;

1. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-access-a-mapped-network-folder-or-unc-path-inside-a-windows-container/22861
2. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/124